# Tooltip isn't being displayed on ScrollPane

Tags: javafx, tooltip, scrollpane

Following the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tooltip.htm) I tried to create a Tooltip on a ScrollPane using the following code:

```
final ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();

scroll.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            point = pointer.getLocation();
            color = robot.getPixelColor((int) point.getX(), (int) point.getY());
            Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
            tooltip.setText(" " + color);
            tooltip.activatedProperty();
            scroll.setTooltip(tooltip);

            System.out.println("Color at: " + point.getX() + "," + point.getY() + " is: " + color);
        }

    });
```

The tooltip however refuses to show itself on the ScrollPane but the output of "Color at: ..." is being printed so I am sure that handle is being called.

EDIT : On the suggestion of jewelsea , I tried putting the eventHandler on the content ,rather than the pane, but to no effect.

Comment: It seems more likely that you would want to apply this routine to the content node of the scroll pane rather than the scroll pane itself - what happens when you do that?

Comment: I modified my code to the content ,which in this is case is an imageview , gave him that eventHandler ,but to no avail. I even tried to put that eventHandler on a button I put there as well and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you really only need to install the tooltip once, and then just modify its text as the mouse moves.

This works for me:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageTooltipTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Image image = new Image("http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/30000/velka/tropical-paradise.jpg");
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(image);
        final ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane();
        scroller.setContent(imageView);

        final Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
        scroller.setTooltip(tooltip);

        scroller.getContent().addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, event -> {
            Image snapshot = scroller.getContent().snapshot(null, null);
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            PixelReader pixelReader = snapshot.getPixelReader();
            Color color = pixelReader.getColor(x, y);
            String text = String.format("Red: %.2f%nGreen: %.2f%nBlue: %.2f", 
                    color.getRed(),
                    color.getGreen(),
                    color.getBlue());
            tooltip.setText(text);
        });



        root.setCenter(scroller);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! Is it perhaps because the initialisation of a new Tooltip takes too long?

Comment: Tooltips, by design, don't appear until after a small delay. So constantly resetting it to a new tooltip as the mouse moves could well prevent it from ever appearing (though I don't actually know the implementation details).

Comment: True, though I tried to keep my mouse still for more than 10 seconds

Comment: But isn't it perfectly conceivable that you have to move the mouse on the Node after the tooltip has been set in order to make the node aware that it needs to be ready to show it? Anyway: there is no reason whatsoever to keep changing the tooltip instance.